# Django: Error-MultipleObjectsReturned while generating a generic list view

Tags: python, django

I have been trying to get Django to return a generic list for my website. I used the following code to create a class view:

```
class ServiceProviderListView(ListView):
    context_object_name = 'contractor_list'
    template_name = 'contractor_list.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        self.service_type = get_object_or_404(ServiceProvider, service_type=self.args[0])
        return ServiceProvider.objects.filter(service_type=self.service_type)
```

However, I keep getting the following error:

```
Exception Type: MultipleObjectsReturned
Exception Value:    
get() returned more than one ServiceProvider -- it returned 736!
```

I copied the code off the Django documentation, but it just does not work. Can anyone help point out the source of the error?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `get_object_or_404(ServiceType....` in first line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should replace it like;

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return ServiceProvider.objects.filter(service_type=self.args[0])
```

`get()` will return only one object, here in your model there will be multiple ServiceProvider objects with same service_type.